# iOS 13 navigationItem.titleView broken

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uinavigationbar

So, I have this piece of code that until now (< iOS 12) just adds a blue rectangle in the UINavigationBar of a UINavigationController-embedded UIViewController. In iOS 13 it doesn't work. Is there something that I'm missing? Maybe because it has no given size? Or is there a new method for setting the NavigationBar's view?

```
navigationItem.titleView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

It looks like this (iOS 12 on the left, iOS 13 on the right):

[image: iOS 12.2, works fine]
[image: iOS 13.0, broken]

Actually, while the animation is happening, it's visible but after that it disappears.

**Edit:**
If you set the `titleView` in `viewDidAppear` it works. But with a delay, not so elegant.

This is what I would like to do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.titleView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
}
```

But what works, as mentioned, is:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.titleView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
}
```

Comment: Hi! You may have already figured this out, but if You do Your creation within the callback function viewDidLayoutSubviews() (override it similarly to what You did in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear), this should work. It does for me.